# Scala releases roadmap

Tags: scala, release

What's the current Scala roadmap? When are Scala 2.10 release and RC's comming?

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any useful information on the web

Comment: You're best off asking [on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scala-user), but you can get some of the info you're looking for in [Odersky's presentation to the SF Scala user group](http://marakana.com/forums/scala/general/575.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala Roadmap Post 2.9.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966068/scala-roadmap-post-2-9-0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has not been made public, probably because there are no hard dates anyway, but we can expect a Scala 2.9.2, likely early this year. Scala 2.10.0 is likely to be released this year, but it's too soon to make any statements about it.

There *might* be a Scala 2.8.3, sort of final release for 2.8.x, like 2.7.7 is for 2.7.x.